# What do brackets mean for mod operation?

Tags: modules

I'm solving equation `5 = (6 * 8 + 9 * b)(mod 10)`. I tried to use wolframalpha and it gives me answer `b = 3`. But if I remove brackets around mod `5 = (6 * 8 + 9 * b) mod 10` it makes a plot, and doesn't give me any real answer. I have no idea how to solve this without guessing the b. So I assume there is some meaning behind those brackets?

Comment: You *do* get the solution just further down on the page.  I do not know why the programs chose to program it so that if you type it without the brackets it will plot a graph and it won't if you include the brackets.  But mathematically it does the same.

Comment: Thanks guys. I got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the brackets it means:
$$5 \equiv (6 \cdot 8 + 9 \cdot b) \pmod{10}$$
It means that every value from $0$ to $9$ is considered an *equivalence class*. (Note that $\LaTeX$ has a special directive for it: `\pmod`.)

You'll see that Wolfram shows this interpretation in its solution:

> Solution in the ***least residue system modulo 10***:
>
> > $b=3$

which is usually written as $b\equiv 3 \pmod{10}$. 
See [Modular Arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic) for more information.

Without the brackets, Wolfram also gives a solution at the bottom, but now it gives all integer solutions.

> ***Integer*** solution:
>
> > $b=10n+3, n\in \mathbb Z$

Answer (score 3):

Okay.

$\pmod n$ means we are doing modulo arithmetic on equivalence classes.

$5 \equiv (6*8 + 9*b)\pmod {10}$ means to find which modulo class $b$ belongs to.

Perhaps a less confusing notation is $5 \equiv_{10} (6*8+9b)$.  The $\pmod {10}$ isn't something you *do*.  It's a statement about what "universe" of arithmetic you are working in.  And we can solve it:

$5 \equiv_{10} (6*8+9b)$

$5 \equiv_{10} 48 + 9b$

$5 \equiv_{10} 8 + (-1)b$

$-3\equiv_{10} -b$

$3 \equiv_{10} b$

$b \equiv 3 \pmod {10}$.

And *without* the parenthesis it means the *similar* but entirely different "gimme the remainder" operation in the "universe" of regualar old arithetic.

$5 = (6*8 + 9b) \mod 10$ means.

The remainder of $(6*8+9b)\div 10$ is $5$

So $48 + 9b = 10n + 5$ for some number $n$

$9b = -43 + 10n$

$9b = 27 + 10(n-6)$

$b = 3 + 10\frac {n-6}9$ for some integer $\frac {n-6}9$.  We don't actually care what $n$ is.  Just that be if $b= 3 + 10k$ we will get that remainder.

So Wolfram is programmed to solve those in different manners.  Even though in practice the results are very very similar.

Note:  $5 = 6*8 + 9b \mod 10$ would be different.

$-43 = (9b \mod 10)$ but $0 \le 9b \mod 10 < 10$ and that can't be $-43$ so this has no solutions.  (Whereas $5 = (6*8 + 9b)\mod 10$ has infinite solutions and $5 \equiv 6*8 + 9b \pmod{10}$ has *one* solution that is an equivalence class that represents *infinitely* many *equivalent* integers.)

Comment: I disagree with your first sentence. While it's true that $a\equiv b\pmod{m}$ means that $a$ and $b$ belong to the same equivalence class in $\Bbb Z/m$, it does not mean that $a$ and $b$ are themselves classes. Actually, $a\equiv b\pmod{m}$ means that $a$ and $b$ are integers such that $m$ divides $a-b$. So, solving the modular equation $f(n)\equiv a \pmod{m}$ does not mean finding an equivalence classe. In general the set of integer solutions $n$ will *not* be an equivalence class modulo $m$ anyway, for instance consider the equation $2^n\equiv 0\pmod2$.

Comment: `9` becomes `-1` because `9 < 10` so you take `9 - 10`?

Comment: "9 becomes -1 because 9 < 10 so you take 9 - 10".  Yes, an no.  Because we are evaluating congruences modulo $10$ we are not concerned with actual integers.  We can replace $9$ with $-1$ (or $19$ or $29$) without any consequence because for our purposes $9$ and $-1$ are equivalent.  And they are equivalent because $9 = -1 + 10k$ for some $k$. I wouldn't have swapped them out in the other interpretation.

Comment: $2^n \equiv 0\pmod 2$ Solve for $n$ is a completely different question.

Comment: Yes, but your formulation of the problem is extremely misleading. You write *"It's a statement about what "universe" of arithmetic you are working in."*, however $b$ is simply a integer here. It's "as if" we were working in $\Bbb Z/10$ because the equation is polynomial. But that's nowhere stated or explained. Note that I have the same concerns with the accepted answer.

Comment: In the equivalence of $a$ and $b$ we can either say that they are integers, or that they are equivalence classes. It's the same thing isomorphically. Your $f(n)$ is not a good example since it only means that $f$ is a function that maps an integer to an equivalence class, or equivalently to an integer @Jean-ClaudeArbaut. TBH, I think you are splitting hairs here.

Comment: Not just splitting hairs but wrong.  $n|a-b \iff a, b\in [k]$ for a specific equivalence class modulo $n$ $\iff [a]$ as an equivalence class $=[b]$ so whether you consider $a \equiv b \pmod n$ to be a statment about $a$ and $b$ and the divisibilty of their difference are whether you think of $a \equiv b \pmod 5$ as an equation of equivalence class, both interpretations are equivalent and interchangeable.  As for $2^n \equiv 0 \mod 2$.  Exponents are not arithmetic.  In *ANY* algebraic structure exponens are integers and not elements of the sturucture so that's irrelevant.

Answer (score 3):

There is some confusion here, due to the use and abuse of various related concepts.

### 1. Congruences and modular arithmetic

You say the integers $a$ and $b$ are congruent modulo $m$ (a positive integer) iff $m$ divide $a-b$ and you write $a\equiv b\pmod{m}$ (and the divisibility relation is written $m\,|\,a-b$). In LaTeX, `a\equiv b\pmod{m}`.

Congruences have a number of nice properties that you can find on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic) and in many books of elementary number theory.

For instance, if $a\equiv b\pmod{m}$ and $c\equiv d\pmod{m}$, then $a+c\equiv b+d\pmod{m}$ and $ac\equiv bd\pmod{m}$. And $\equiv$ is an [equivalence relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation).

Modular arithmetic is said to "wrap around", because if $a\equiv b\pmod{m}$, then $a+km\equiv b\pmod{m}$ for all integers $k$.

And given an integer $a$ you can always find a unique integer $r\in\{0,\dots m-1\}$ such that $a\equiv r\pmod{m}$. This $r$ has a precise meaning: $r$ is the [remainder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remainder) in the [euclidean division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_division) of $a$ by $m$. And the relation $a\equiv b\pmod{m}$ actually means that $a$ and $b$ give the same remainder when divided by $m$.

### 2. Rings, ideals and quotients

Given the [ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_(mathematics)) of integers $\Bbb Z$, any [ideal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_(ring_theory)) has the form $m\Bbb Z$ (it contains the multiples of some positive integer $m$) and you can consider the quotient ring $\Bbb Z/m\Bbb Z$. The [quotient ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_ring) is a ring on the set of classes of integers defined by the equivalence relation $\sim$, on $\Bbb Z$, defined by $a\sim b$ if $a-b\in m\Bbb Z$. You should see the similarity with $m\,|\,a-b$. Historically congruences came before rings and quotient rings, but congruences are actually a special case, and you can do that in any ring as long as you have an ideal and build the quotient ring.

Given the ring $\Bbb Z$ and the quotient ring $\Bbb Z/m\Bbb Z$, you then have a canonical [homomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_homomorphism) $p:\Bbb Z\to\Bbb Z/m\Bbb Z$ that maps any inteer $a$ to its class in $\Bbb Z/m\Bbb Z$.

Then you can prove that $a\equiv b\pmod{m}$ iff $p(a)=p(b)$. More generally, in an arbitrary ring, and given an ideal $\frak a$, you can define $a\equiv b\pmod{\frak a}$ iff $p(a)=p(b)$.

As you can see, all of this looks more abstract than congruences, but it's a very similar concept in disguise.

Additionally, the notation for $p(a)$ can vary. It's sometimes written $cl(a)$, or even $\dot a$. For instance, with $m=3$, there are $3$ congruence classes, $\{3k\,/\,k\in\Bbb Z\}$, $\{3k+1\,/\,k\in\Bbb Z\}$ and $\{3k+2\,/\,k\in\Bbb Z\}$. Each one can be denoted by any element of the class, for instance $\Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z=\{cl(27),cl(82),cl(-1)\}$, but it's common to use a unique representative element, and it's natural to take the $r$ defined earlier, that is the remainder in the euclidean division. Here the elements of $\Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z$ would be written $\dot0,\dot1,\dot2$. When the context is clear enough, it's a common abuse of notation to write simply $0,1,2$, but I think the temptation should be resisted.

### 3. Computer science

Congruences are very useful but sometimes you want a notation for the actual remainder. Programming languages all have a way to denote the remainder, with an additional caveat. Pascal and Ada use `a mod b`, C and C-like languages use `a%b`, and notations such as `mod(a,b)` or `rem(a,b)` is not uncommon. However, languages have various interpretations on what the result is when $a$ or $b$ is negative, see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation).

There is a recent tendency, especially in discrete mathematics and computer science, to define the operator $a\mod b$ to be the remainder in the euclidean division. It's also possible to extend the definition to arbitrary real numbers $a,b$ (with $b\ne0$), and this also exists for floating-point arithmetic in programming languages.

For integers $a,b$, $a\mod b$ is thus an integer, and for real $a,b$ it's a real.

Now, there is again a similarity with $a\equiv b\pmod m$. Specifically, if $0\le b<m$, then $b=a\mod m$ (read $b=(a\mod m)$ if your are in doubt). Likewise, you have always $a\equiv (a\mod m) \pmod{m}$.

### 4. And $a=b \pmod m$?

This is a notation I would not advocate. I believe it's mainly used to mean the same as $a\equiv b\pmod m$, but it's misleading: it's not really an equality, the $\pmod m$ part is crucial here. Or it could mean an equality in $\Bbb Z/m\Bbb Z$. Since it's not entirely clear what is meant, and it's too similar to $a=b\mod m$ (where $\mathrm{mod}$ is the operator), I think it's a bad idea to use it.

### 5. WolframAlpha's strange plot.

You have now everything to understand why WolframAlpha is adding a plot when going from [5 = (6 * 8 + 9 * b) (mod 10)](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=5%20%3D%20(6%20*%208%20%2B%209%20*%20b)%20(mod%2010)) to [5 = (6 * 8 + 9 * b) mod 10](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=5+%3D+(6+*+8+%2B+9+*+b)+mod+10). The former is a congruence and is used only with integers. The latter is an operator that can be defined on reals. In the plot, WolframAlpha is just showing how it interprets $5\mod10$ and $(9b+48)\mod 10$: the intersection is where there is equality.

### 6. How do you solve this equation?

Your equation can be written $5\equiv 9b+48\pmod{10}$.

Since $5\equiv5\pmod{10}$, your equation is equivalent to $0\equiv 9b+43\pmod{10}$ (remember you can subtract two congruences with the same modulus).

Since $b\equiv b\pmod{10}$ your equation is equivalent to $b\equiv 10b+43\pmod{10}$.

Finally since you don't change the congruence by adding or subtracting a multiple of the modulus ($10$), your equation is equivalent to

$$b\equiv3 \pmod{10}$$

That is, the set of solutions is the set of integers such that $10\,|\,b-3$, which means $b=10k+3$ for some integer $k$. The set of solution is thus $\{10k+3\,/\,k\in\Bbb Z\}$.

Comment: If it is given that $a,b \in \mathbb Z/m$, there's nothing wrong with saying that $a=b$, with or without the $\bmod{m}$. Nor saying that $a\equiv b$, with or without the $\pmod{m}$. It's all a matter of context. And even that becomes irrelevant if there is no room for confusion about what we're talking about.

Comment: I don't think notation is ever irrelevant. If only because a standard and uniform notation eases reading. If I read $2$, I expect it's an integer, not an "irrelevant detail" according to the writer.

Comment: Your use of $\mathbb Z/m$ is the first time I've seen it. For instance wiki does not mention it. Given the context I immediately understand what you mean, but strictly speaking, it's the set $\{0,\pm 1/m, \pm 2/m,\ldots\}$. Just saying.

Comment: @IlikeSerena I have seen this in several places, but I don't like it either. I thought it was well known. I have also seen $\Bbb Z_n$ by the way. Of course, as long as textbooks give the definition, it's ok, but you are right, it's not a good habit as it can be confused with something ele (however, I would rather write $\frac1n\Bbb Z$ for the set you mention, to avoid confusion). I will remove this one from the answer.

Comment: Yes, I am used to either $\mathbb Z_n$ or $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$. It remains ambiguous whether it is the additive group, the ring, or just the set of elements though. To remove the ambiguity, we should write something like _'the ring $(\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z,+,\cdot)$ with the usual addition and multiplication'_, which is usually considered to be a bit long winded.